# Global variables not accessible to ajax loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Index.**html**

```
<script>
var foo = 1;
</script>
```

This **html** page is loaded several times into the page using AJAX:

post.**html**

```
<script>
if (foo === 1)
{
// do something
}
// Error: foo is not defined
</script>
```

Foo is just a variable that is determined if the browser has AJAX capabilities. Since the script is loaded in via AJAX, that should mean that the browser is able to make XMLHTTPRequests.

I'd rather not have to change the contents of post.html and index.html.

Is there a way to set `foo = 1` in post.html before it's loaded into the index.html?

```
(anonymous function)    @   VM10881:2
jQuery.extend.globalEval    @   app.js:329
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip   @   app.js:5436
jQuery.fn.extend.after  @   app.js:5245
verifyPage  @   app.js:9319
completed   @   app.js:9289
onComplete  @   app.js:9250
jQuery.Callbacks.fire   @   app.js:3100
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith  @   app.js:3212
done    @   app.js:8265
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

Comment: Why not just check `if(window.XMLHttpRequest)`?

Comment: @Johan because I'd have to replace foo with window.foo and var foo with window.foo and I don't know how to do that. I'm not the one that created the JS in the script tags. There must be an easier way to do this, I just don't know what to Google search. I tried "script variable on page not accessible in loaded script"

Comment: So you're saying even though `post.html` is dynamically loaded in to `index.html`, it can't access `foo`, which is defined in `index.htm`?

Comment: @Johan, Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on.. My plan C is to just remove the script tags from the post.html

Comment: Hmm, you could prepend a new script tag with foo set to 1 before adding it to index.htm

Comment: @Johan Alright that worked, but now the objects inside of the if statement are not defined. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try something similar to what I did below. Does that work?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think I'd run into more issues because I need to use $ and another constructor inside of the if statement. This is a mess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (from index.htm):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'post.htm',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(html){

    var $html = $(html),
        script = '<script>var foo=1;</script>';

   $html.find('head').prepend(script);

   $('body').append($html);
});
```

Comment: You know what might be the problem? I'm stripping everything except the body contents of the page that I made an AJAX request to. Could this be why everything is undefined? Should I store the head of the page somewhere? And the thing is, I'm not trying to append the entire HTML page, I'm stripping the contents of it (tables) and the tables have scripts that literally use the same variables as the current page's global variables

Comment: I was looking at this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1930108.aspx?Script+issues+when+partial+view+is+added+to+page+via+ajax+calls Is it related?